# Django superuser admin

Tags: django, django-admin, localhost, user-input, superuser

I can't load the admin login screen.

have opened a Web browser and went to “/admin/” on  local domain  **http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/**
was supposed to open admin login window.

Comment: What does the browser say? Page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if your Django server is running.You can do that, by typing `python manage.py runserver` in the terminal and then visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ in your browser.

Second, check if the Django admin is enabled. Open `settings.py` in your project folder and check if `INSTALLED_APPS` list has the `django.contrib.admin` element.

Third, check if you have an admin.py file in your app directory. The code should looks something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Fourth, Check for your login credentials in your Django settings. Go to your project's `settings.py` file and you have to have this code:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'
```

And the last option is to try clearing your browser cache and cookies and restarting the server.